# Hide/Show css div with javascript - does not show again after hide -

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, html, hide

The div 'container' is hidden once I do a mouseover. When I do again a mouseover on the empty space where the div is supposed to be nothing happens means its not getting visible.

What do I wrong?

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

   <script type="text/javascript">
       function ShowUserInterface(containerToSwitch) {
           debugger;
           var element = document.getElementById(containerToSwitch);

           if (element.getAttribute("visibility") == "hidden")
               element.setAttribute("style", "visibility: visible");
           else
               element.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden");  


       }
</script> 
<div  style="visibility:visible;width:200px;height:200px;background-color:Aqua" onmouseover="ShowUserInterface(this.id)" id="container" >
    <uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" />
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so focused on a div... Now doing the display: none/block with a table and it work.

Answer (score 3):

Hidden element can't fire events, so in your case I see only one possible solution: use `style.opacity = 0` and `style.opacity = 1` instead of `style.visibility = 'hidden'` and `style.visibility = 'visible'`. But this won't work in old browsers.

Also if you want to get some style attribute use `element.style.visibility`, not `element.getAttribute('visibility')`:

```
if (element.style.visibility == "hidden")
    element.style.visibility = "visible";
else
    element.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Or better use some js framework (jQuery, prototype.js, mootools), especially if your project requires much of JavaScript.

Comment: Hidden element can't fire events, so in your case I see only one possible solution: use `style.opacity = 0` and `style.opacity = 1` instead of `style.visibility = 'hidden'` and `style.visibility = 'visible'`. But this won't work in old browsers.

Comment: @bjornd your comment is the only one so far which actually refer to the fact the event won't fire. Consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: For IE from 6 to 8 (I consider IE5 completely dead) you can add specific style definitions, read [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html). I recommend you to create CSS rules for hidden and visible elements and toggle classes then, not properties of element's style.

Comment: IE 8 can not toggle class names which has an immediate effect. Firefox an others can it but not IE 8!

Answer (score 0):

try this

"
if (element.style.visibility == "hidden")
               element.style.visibility = "visible";
           else
               element.style.visibility = "hidden";
"

Answer (score 0):

This function clears all previous style info so not a best practice do toogle something.

Instead use

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: it just hides the div after the 2nd mouseover, why this?

Comment: because your default `e.style.display` is not block for the first time. add `display:block to` your style and let me know if it works.

Comment: did not work means the div with display:none did not get block(visible) again. :/ Now I try the opacity hint.

Comment: btw. I am using INTERNET EXPLORER 8 here and can not try any other browser in company.

Answer (score 0):

Your checking for the `visibility` attribute on the element, but it's actually on the `style` object -- but you might be surprised with results even when you do `element.style.visibility` as this might not always give you the right result (in your case it will, because your setting inline styles which is bad practice anyway)

Let's assume you set your CSS style on the element like so:

```
#user { visibility: hidden; }
```

Then you checked for it:

```
alert(document.getElementById('user').style.visibility);
```

It'll contain an empty string `""` -- instead you should ideally use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.getComputedStyle) to actually get what styles are *IN USE.*